# Converting a Dataframe into Series of Pandas Series

Tags: python, pandas, plot

How can i convert a dataframe into series of Pandas series.
My dataframe below and i want it to plot with stacked bar chart.

```
    city  soru_id value1 value2 value3 value4 value5
0      1        2    147    119     69     92    106
1      2        2     31     20     12     14     26
2      3        2     37     22     24     18     19
3      4        2     10     13      7     13     10
4      5        2     38     48     18     30     27
5      6        2    401    409    168    354    338
..   ...      ...    ...    ...    ...    ...    ...
76    77        2     12      7      3     12      8
77    78        2      4      2      1     12      3
78    79        2      3   None      1   None   None
79    80        2     12      7      4      4      7
80    81        2     18     13      7     10      2

[81 rows x 7 columns]
```

Therefore i need to get the dataframe into form like below to plot it. I can not loop into DataFrame() method. How can i plot it.

```
df = pd.DataFrame([pd.Series([value1,value2,value3,value4,value5]), 
        pd.Series([value1,value2,value3,value4,value5]), 
        pd.Series([value1,value2,value3,value4,value5]),
        ..................................
        ..................................
        pd.Series([value1,value2,value3,value4,value5]),
        pd.Series([value1,value2,value3,value4,value5])
        ], index=[index0,index2,index3,....,index79,index80])

df.plot.bar(stacked=True)
plt.show()
```

Comment: This seems like an XY problem.  You just want to plot the values from each row?

Comment: Each row in the dataframe is already a series.

Comment: What does your desired output chart look like?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to change anything about your dataframe, just index the dataframe based on your value columns and plot that.

```
cols = [col for col in df.columns if col.startswith('value')]
df[cols].plot.bar(stacked=True)
plt.show()
```

[image]